# How to monitor volume level during ffmpeg capture

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, volume

I capture sound from soundcard, convert it to mp3 and stream to multicast IP. 
Command looks like:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0 -async 1 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -flush_packets 0 -f mpegts -pes_payload_size 426 -mpegts_start_pid 0x44 udp://233.21.215.101:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

But I need to monitor volume level of capturing. If there is no sound (or noise only) I need to switch to another (reserve) channel.

Can I get volume level in ffmpeg output? How I can do it?

P.S: I can get volume level by "volumedetect" filter but it's not in realtime. I need realtime monitoring.

P.P.S: I run ffmpeg programmatically from my application and can't monitor additional windows (like video frame when I use showvolume filter).

Answer (score 2):

Right now, I can suggest using the `showvolume` filter

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0
       -async 1 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k
       -flush_packets 0 -f mpegts
       -pes_payload_size 426 -mpegts_start_pid 0x44 udp://233.21.215.101:1234?pkt_size=1316
       -filter_complex showvolume[a] -map [a] -f sdl -
```

A small video window will pop up with a bar graph display of the current volume and also as text labels. You'll need a ffmpeg build with SDL library linked.

You can't close this video window while your streaming is active.

Comment: Thanx, but I run ffmpeg from my application and I can't monitor video window. But I found silencedetect filter. Now I try to use it.